# How many Israelites were punished for the golden calf?

Tags: capital-punishment, parashat-ki-tisa, golden-calf-egel

[We know](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9893#showrashi=true&v=20) that 3,000 were killed by sword as punishment for the sin of the golden calf. But how many were killed by the plague, and how many by the water ordeal? (How many of these were B'nei Yisroel and how many were the Erev Rav?) Do any of our sources tell us?

Related:

- [Why are we so concerned about 1/2 of 1% (Golden Calf episode)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56214/why-are-we-so-concerned-about-1-2-of-1-golden-calf-episode?rq=1)
- [Did all of Bnei Israel worship the golden calf?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26942/did-all-of-bnei-israel-worship-the-golden-calf)

Comment: This might help answer your question:
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103719/how-many-people-participated-in-the-golden-calf